android.system.ErrnoException - connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
This issue not generating on testing but when the Application is live this issue comes in firbase. I have checked in multiple networks but getting issues in the Play Store built-in firbase. I have increase
 private fun getOrderOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        try {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

            builder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(
                            "Header",
                            UtilityMethods.getAuthorizationToken("getData", HeaderData, AppData)
                        )
                        .addHeader("Date", "12/07/08")
                        .addHeader(
                            "MinHeader",
                            UtilityMethods.postAuthorizationToken(Key, header)
                        )
                        .build()
                    chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }
            return builder.build()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            return builder.build()
        }


What does 'I have increase' mean, and where is the rest of that sentence?
